# Fill up date gap by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table of products and their sales quantity in months.

```
Product Month      Qty
A       2018-01-01 5
A       2018-02-01 3
A       2018-05-01 5
B       2018-08-01 10
B       2018-10-01 12
...
```

I'd like to first fill in the data gap between each product's min and max dates like below:

```
Product Month      Qty
A       2018-01-01 5
A       2018-02-01 3
A       2018-03-01 0
A       2018-04-01 0
A       2018-05-01 5
B       2018-08-01 10
B       2018-09-01 0
B       2018-10-01 12
...
```

Then I would need to perform an accumulation of each product's sales quantity by month.

```
Product Month      total_Qty
A       2018-01-01 5
A       2018-02-01 8
A       2018-03-01 8
A       2018-04-01 8
A       2018-05-01 13
B       2018-08-01 10
B       2018-09-01 10
B       2018-10-01 22
...
```

I fumbled over the "cross join" clause, however it seems to generate some unexpected results for me. Could someone help to give a hint how I can achieve this in SQL?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You will need a "Calendar" table to provide the missing date & you left join from that.... Either use an existing (if available) or generate one via a sql CTE...

Comment: Hi i think you have to see CTE (WITH clause) AND OVER PARTITION BY .
What is your SQL Server version ?

Comment: @john McTighe Thanks for the comment. I could add a "calendar" table. However, the problem is I have different min and max date for different products. I do not want to have all of them using the same "calendar"

Comment: @got2nosth hi yhink you have to perform with specific product calendar table like Product, DateMonth

Comment: @pascal sanchez Thanks for the thoughts. The challenge with PARTITION BY is I would miss the sum for non-existing months, like 2018-03-01 for my product A. I'm using SQL server 2017

Comment: @got2nosth take look at the answer i have update some mistake :) i think you have workaround and build query with this approch (you can also build the temp calandar product table with Dynamic SQL "EXECUTE")

Comment: @got2nosth "However, the problem is I have different min and max date for different products." This problem should be explained as part of the question... anyway it does not change the fact that you need a calendar table (not necessarily a physical table), what it can change is the way to join it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a recursive CTE is a simple way to do this.  The code is just:

```
with cte as (
      select product, min(mon) as mon, max(mon) as end_mon
      from t
      group by product
      union all
      select product, dateadd(month, 1, mon), end_mon
      from cte
      where mon < end_mon
     )
select cte.product, cte.mon, coalesce(qty, 0) as qty
from cte left join
     t
     on t.product = cte.product and t.mon = cte.mon;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3aebad991c6b1a35050b3a6e1314b86) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Is not too expensive for the server to do that with a large list of products over several months??

Comment: @DanielBrughera . . . I don't think so.  You have to aggregate the original data to get the limits, generate all the rows anyway, and then join back to get the original data -- regardless of the approach.  Recursive CTEs might add a little over head to the first part of the problem (relative to other methods), but you would need to test the solutions to see if it had a significant effect.  I don't think it would.

Comment: I compared the execution plans... my way requires less memory but yours is faster, the final costs are very similar.... but contrariety with my original though yours uses less CPU

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks a lot! Never thought a recursive cte can work this well! Btw, I have one small implementation detail to clarify. Why is it mon < end_mon instead of mon <= end_mon? I verified that "<" is the correct condition, but why the date range can cover the end_mon without being equal to the maximum?

Comment: @got2nosth . . . Because the `select` is adding one month to the date.  If you use `<=` you will get one value after the end month.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this example can help you and perform what you excepted :

```
  CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(Product   varchar(10),  
   ProductMonth      DATETIME,
   Qty      int
  );  
GO  

CREATE TABLE #MyTableTempDate  
(
   FullMonth      DATETIME
  );  
GO  


INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 'A', '2019-01-01',  214
UNION
SELECT 'A', '2019-02-01',  4
UNION 
SELECT 'A', '2019-03-01',  50
UNION
SELECT 'B', '2019-01-01',  214
UNION
SELECT 'B', '2019-02-01',  10
UNION 
SELECT 'C', '2019-04-01', 150


INSERT INTO #MyTableTempDate
SELECT '2019-01-01'
UNION
SELECT '2019-02-01'
UNION
SELECT '2019-03-01'
UNION
SELECT '2019-04-01'
UNION
SELECT '2019-05-01'
UNION
SELECT '2019-06-01'
UNION
SELECT '2019-07-01';

------------- FOR NEWER SQL SERVER VERSION  > 2005

WITH MyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT T.Product, T.ProductMonth AS 'MMonth', T.Qty
    FROM #MyTable T
    UNION
    SELECT T.Product, TD.FullMonth AS 'MMonth', 0 AS 'Qty'
    FROM #MyTable T, #MyTableTempDate TD
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #MyTable TT WHERE TT.Product = T.Product AND TD.FullMonth = TT.ProductMonth)
)
-- SELECT * FROM MyCTE;
SELECT Product, MMonth, Qty, SUM( Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY  Product 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'TotalQty'
FROM MyCTE
ORDER BY Product, MMonth ASC;


DROP TABLE  #MyTable


DROP TABLE  #MyTableTempDate
```

I have other way to perform this in lower SQL Server Version (like 2005 and lower)
It's a SELECT on SELECT if it's your case let me know and i provide some other example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any other way i can create this temp table for date?  I have in fact thousands of rows of products and dates in different combinations.

Comment: @got2nosth i think you can build temporary table for specific product but i didn't know other way ... or you have to insert in your table the line at 0 for product for month and this can be a (scheduled monthly worker "planified task")

Comment: @Pascal once you are populating your calendar table manually, then you don;t need CTEs or UNIONS... simply LEFT JOIN will do the same, and compatible with all versions.....

Comment: @DanielBrughera yes but who your’re link product with left join ?

Comment: In my case I used a subquery to get also max and min dates per product, I read in the comments that the PO requires different start and end dates per product...

Comment: @DanielBrughera yes i’m looking your answer but i think the query it’s unclear hi miss some information i think they have other table to find min date and max date by product

Comment: Then can replace that part of the query, with the provided schema is the way I found to get those values

Comment: Before see that comment I used SELECT DISTINCT ProductID in the subquery joining on 1=1 to get all dates for all products.... gettting the same result as you have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190364/discussion-between-daniel-brughera-and-pascal-sanchez).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would divide month and year to get easier with statistics.

I will give you an example query, not based on your table but still helpful.

```
--here i create the table that will be used as calendar
Create Table MA_MonthYears (
Month int  not null ,
year int  not null 
PRIMARY KEY ( month, year) )

--/////////////////


-- here i'm creating a procedure to fill the ma_monthyears table
declare @month as int 
declare @year as int
set @month = 1
set @year = 2015

while ( @year != 2099  )
begin

insert into MA_MonthYears(Month, year)
select @month, @year

if @month < 12 
set @month=@month+1
else
set @month=1

if @month = 1 
set @year = @year + 1 

end

--/////////////////


--here you are the possible result you are looking for
select SUM(Ma_saledocdetail.taxableamount) as Sold, MA_MonthYears.month , MA_MonthYears.year , item
from MA_MonthYears left outer join MA_SaleDocDetail on year(MA_SaleDocDetail.DocumentDate) = MA_MonthYears.year 
and Month(ma_saledocdetail.documentdate) = MA_MonthYears.Month
group by MA_SaleDocDetail.Item, MA_MonthYears.year , MA_MonthYears.month
order by  MA_MonthYears.year , MA_MonthYears.month
```

Comment: It doesnt match the requirement

Comment: tell why instead of only criticize, so everybody will be helped by your suggestions

Comment: It's not criticism, It's a fact, did you test your query?? It returns null values when the PO posted the desired output

Comment: I am not judging the way you get the result

Comment: If it worked for you for a different purpose doesn't mean that it works for this one.... mock it up with the provided input and you will see the substantial differences

Answer (score 0):

You can create the months with a recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE   
(  
    ProductID  CHAR(1),  
    Date      DATE,
    Amount      INT
) 

INSERT INTO @MyTable 
VALUES 
('A','2018-01-01', 5),
('A','2018-02-01', 3),
('A','2018-05-01', 5),
('B','2018-08-01', 10),
('B','2018-10-01', 12)

DECLARE @StartDate DATE 
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SELECT @StartDate = MIN(Date), @EndDate = MAX(Date) FROM @MyTable

;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Month, 1, Date)
    FROM dates 
    WHERE Date < @EndDate   
)
SELECT A.ProductID, d.Date, COALESCE(Amount,0) AS Amount, COALESCE(SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ProductID ORDER BY  A.ProductID, d.Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0) AS Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT ProductID, MIN(date) as DateStart, MAX(date) as DateEnd 
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY ProductID -- As I read in your comments that you need different min and max dates per product
) A 
JOIN dates d ON d.Date >= A.DateStart AND d.Date <= A.DateEnd
LEFT JOIN @MyTable T ON A.ProductID = T.ProductID AND T.Date =  d.Date
ORDER BY A.ProductID, d.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp')  IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
;WITH CTE(Product,[Month],Qty)
AS
(
SELECT 'A','2018-01-01', 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2018-02-01', 3  UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2018-05-01', 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2018-08-01', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D','2018-10-01', 12
)
SELECT ct.Product,[MonthDays],ct.Qty 
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
SELECT c.Product,[Month],
       ISNULL(Qty,0) AS Qty 
FROM CTE c
)ct
RIGHT JOIN
(
 SELECT -- This code is to get month data
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2018-'+ RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MM, s.number, CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)))AS VARCHAR),2) +'-01',120) AS [MonthDays]         
 FROM master.dbo.spt_values s 
 WHERE [type] = 'P' AND s.number BETWEEN 0 AND 11
)DT
ON dt.[MonthDays] = ct.[Month]


SELECT   
        MAX(Product)OVER(ORDER BY [MonthDays])AS Product,
        [MonthDays],        
        ISNULL(Qty,0) Qty,
        SUM(ISNULL(Qty,0))OVER(ORDER BY [MonthDays]) As SumQty
FROM #Temp
```

Result

```
Product MonthDays   Qty SumQty
------------------------------
A       2018-01-01  5   5
A       2018-02-01  3   8
A       2018-03-01  0   8
A       2018-04-01  0   8
A       2018-05-01  5   13
A       2018-06-01  0   13
A       2018-07-01  0   13
B       2018-08-01  10  23
B       2018-09-01  0   23
D       2018-10-01  12  35
D       2018-11-01  0   35
D       2018-12-01  0   35
```

Comment: The question was incomplete , so i thought for days ,that does means solution is wrong

Comment: The date format is not correct, and, assuming that it is for days.... it only works for january

Comment: I think that there are some ambiguities in the question, but you are making assumptions that don't match with the expected outputs provided, for example what to do with dates 6 and 7.... it is clarified in the question's comments... not the right place, i know, but is there...